# Creating Custom Join in Django

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-views

I am struggling to create the correct prefetch behavior in Django. Here is the outline of the problem:

- Each Account has DailyQuotes, updated daily at different times (think snapshot)
- Need to query all of those DailyQuotes, and only get the most recent quotes for each account

Here are the models:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(default="")
    ...

class DailyQuotes(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name="quote", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=None)
    ...
```

Currently the query inside of my view for this looks like:

```
acc_ids = [1,2,3]
max_date = DailyQuotes.objects.aggregate(Max("date"))["date__max"]
accounts = (
            Account.objects.filter(id__in=acc_ids)
            .prefetch_related(
                Prefetch(
                    "quote",
                    queryset=DailyQuotes.objects.filter(date=date),
                ),
            )
        )
# Feed into serializer, etc
```

This works and generates 3 queries: 1 for the max date, 1 for accounts, and 1 for the quotes. The problem with this solution is that if one account has more up to date DailyQuotes, then the other accounts will return no quotes. So I need to get the latest DailyQuotes for each account based on the max date for that account, not all accounts.

I have generated the SQL query that does what I want, but turning it into Django code has been giving me issues. I could execute the raw SQL but I would like to keep it in Django. Here is what the current SQL looks like and what it needs to be:

Current prefetch query (generated by Django):

```
SELECT ... FROM dailyquotes
    WHERE (dailyquotes.date = 2022-05-05
           AND dailyquotes.account_id IN (1,2,3))
```

Required prefetch query (or similar):

```
SELECT ... FROM dailyquotes dq
    JOIN (SELECT account_id, MAX(date) AS date__max FROM dailyquotes
          WHERE account_id in (1,2,3) group by account_id) dates 
    ON dq.account_id = dates.account_id AND dq.date = dates.date__max
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

With some help from SamSparx, here is what I came up with:

```
acc_ids = [1,2,3]
max_dates = (DailyQuotes.objects.filter(account_id__in=acc_ids)
            .values("account_id")
            .annotate(max_date=Max("date")))

recordsets = None

# get the recordsets
for max_date in max_dates:
    qs = DailyQuotes.objects.filter(
        account_id=max_date["account_id"], 
        date=max_date["max_date"])
        
    if recordsets is None:
        recordsets = qs
    else:
        recordsets = recordsets | qs

accounts = (Account.objects.filter(
            id__in=permissions["acc_ids"].values())
            .prefetch_related(
                Prefetch(
                    "quote",
                    queryset=recordsets,
                ),
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not tied to prefetch_related you can do it in Django via DailyQuotes in 2 calls - 1 to gather the max dates and 1 for the final recordset (even using select_related if you want accompanying account info).

```py
from django.db.models import Max

#define lists
acc_ids = [0,1,2]
max_dates = []
recordsets = []
final_recordset = []
    
#get the max date for each account ID
max_dates = DailyQuotes.objects.filter(account_id__in=acc_ids).values('account_id').annotate(max_date = Max('date'))

#get the recordsets
for max_date in max_dates:
    qs = DailyQuotes.objects.filter(account_id = max_date['account_id'], date = max_date['max_date'] )
    #qs =  DailyQuotes.objects.filter(account_id = max_date['account_id'], date = max_date['max_date']).select_related('account') if you need associated account info
    recordsets.append(qs)
        
#combine the recordsets for serialising  - you may want to modify this based on length of recordsets list (in case of empty accounts) for robustness  
final_recordset = recordsets[0].union( recordsets[1], recordsets[2])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had a similar query for getting the max_dates that you did, and it seems to generate the correct SQL that we are wanting. However I think the only problem with this solution would be that it would do a query for each account / dq (N+1 problem right?), rather than a single query to get all accounts / dq. That was the reason I was trying to pack it up into that single query with prefetch. This gives me some ideas though, so I'll see if I can come up with something that will work. Thanks!

Comment: I actually ran a version of it through django_debug_toolbar to test this before submitting and its only two. The max_dates recordset is a single call and django's lazy evaluation means the recordsets in 'recordsets' don't get evaluated until the final .union, which combines them all into one sql call. So you should be able to add as many accounts as you like without undue overhead.

Comment: That is true, I forgot about that. After some changes I got it to work and while the query does some unnecessary filtering because of the prefetch, it is still super fast with the correct indexes. Added my final code in an edit. Thanks for the help